# JavaScript: Change image based on value typed in a textbox

Tags: javascript, image, textbox, onchange

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a JavaScript onChange event to change the SRC for an image based on a number typed in a textbox on a form.  For example, if the user types a number beginning with the number 3, I'd like to SRC to point to one image, but if the user types a number beginning with the number 4, I'd like the SRC to point to a different image, and I'd like other SRC changes when the user types a number beginning with 5, or a number beginning with 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something to watch out for: Usually, the `change` event doesn't get fired until after the textbox has *lost focus*. You might want to use `onkeydown` instead.

Comment: Up-voted to offset the down-vote simply because I didn't see a commented reason for the down vote. Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, all for your help.

:)

Here is the final solution I developed.  I used an onkeyup event, as it was better suited to my needs.  The HTML I used:

```
    <form name="AddCardToAccount" id="AddCardToAccount" action="" method="post"> 
    <img id="imgCC" name="imgCC" class="imgCC" src="/includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif">
    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" size="31" onkeyup="handleKeypress(this,event);">
```

I added some case numbers to cover the numbers of the key pad, in addition to the numbers of the keyboard. Here is the JavaScript I used:

```
        function handleKeypress(inCardNumber,e) {
            var inCardNumber = document.AddCardToAccount.cardNumber;
            var imgToSwap = document.AddCardToAccount.imgCC; 
            var charCode;
            if(e && e.which){
                charCode = e.which; // For Firefox
                }
                else if(window.event){

                    e = window.event;
                    charCode = e.keyCode; // For IE

            }
            if (inCardNumber.value.length === 1) { 
                switch (charCode) { 
                    case (48):
                        imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                    case (49):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                        break;
                    case (50):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (51):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgAmexCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (52):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgVisaCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (53):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgMcCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (54):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgDiscCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (55):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (56):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (57):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (96):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (97):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (98):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (99):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgAmexCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (100):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgVisaCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (101):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgMcCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (102):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgDiscCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (103):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (104):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
                case (105):
                    imgToSwap.src = "includes/sci/images/imgNoCC_.gif";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have provided a fully commented [example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9yJQ/) of how this can be done.

**html**

```
<input id="myid" type="text">
<img id="myimg" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
```

**javascript**

```
window.onload = function() { // because we are grabbing DOM elements we need to ensure the elements are first loaded.
    var elm = document.getElementById("myid"),
        img = document.getElementById("myimg"); // here we grab the input box and the image
    elm.onkeyup = function(event) { // capture the input keyup
        if (this.value.length === 1) { // make sure we are only checking the first value
            switch (event.keyCode) { // here we are running the switch statement against the keyup event keycode value
            case (48): 
                img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=0";
                break;
            case (49):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1";
                break;
            case (50):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2";
                break;
            case (51):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3";
                break;
            case (52):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=4";
                break;
            case (53):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=5";
                break;
            case (54):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=6";
                break;
            case (55):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=7";
                break;
            case (56):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=8";
                break;
            case (57):
                 img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=9";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So, instead of this, case (48): 
                img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=0";
                break;
should I use this? case (48): 
                img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=0"+".gif";
                break;

Comment: `img.src = "whatever"` whatever being the address of the image your want to display.