# Show specific image when a number is within a range

Tags: javascript, php

Hello fellow helpers :) 
I have the issue that I want to show a specific one of 30 images, depending on a value which is sent by an access-query into a website. 
I searched the netfor many answers, and some came close, yet never to where I wanted. Is there anyone that can help me out with this. It can be JS or PHP, both is fine.

So as an example: Value hits 1376, then the image will be number 4, when the value hits 1377 the image should be number 5. Value should be easily changeable.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377711/javascript-change-image-based-on-value-typed-in-a-textbox) did not do, what it should - but looks like something that might be easily edited (if you know how).

This should have been a website, where a specific number is shown (betweeen 1 and 10000), depending on achievements. When this value hits a certain minimum-value, I would want to show the corresponding image. For when it is below 1000, it would show "under 10%"-image. Between 1000 and 1499 it would be the "close to 15%"-image. 
So actually a visualisation of the progress. Not as a bar, but as images. Imageine a house being build and with every number, one more stone is put onto the fundament. That would be the intention. 
I hope that makes sense now. If not, don't flag the whole question, but ask.

Comment: provide ur existing or attempd code.. so i start code for you.. means where i shart code..what is ur flow of code.

Comment: I tried it as in the link posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="<?php echo php ?>" method = "post" >
<input type="text" name="number" value="1376" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
<?php 
$path = '4.jpg';
$value = $_POST['number'];
if(!(empty($value)){
    $path = explode($path,'.');
 switch($value) {
 case 1366:
    $path = 4; //incrementing by one
    break;
 case 1367:
    $path = 5; //incrementing by one
    break;
default:
    $path = 4;
    break;
 }  
}
$path = $path.'.'.$path[1];

?>
<img class="hidden" src="<?php echo $path ?>"/>
```

this one uses case structure. Set as you wish.

Comment: That looks good. So on load of the page it will check the value and display the corresponding image, right? And I can extend the list to 30 cases? The image ".jpg" is set and I only need to define the name, right?

Comment: [code]<img class="hidden" src="<?php echo $path ?>"/> [/code]

That one seems to be not working?

Comment: yeah...you can remove the 'hidden' class, forgot it there. Tick as answer if correct. I believe n know this works. Add as many cases as you would like @DimitriVlaanderen

Comment: I might be missing something? Can you check: http://www.marykaypromotion.de/sah/cons.html that contains the code, I am trying with. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you help, project is cancelled :( And no, it is not because of you ;-)

Comment: ok doke. Welcome a bunch